# Solve a recursive system of two equations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

the problem I need to solve is a system of two equations, like this:

```
(*First Equation*)   y == -x/Tan[x]

(*Second Equation*) x^2 + y^2 == A*f^2
```

where `A==5.14*10^-20`, and `f` is a value that goes from `6.00*10^9` to `30.00*10^9`, and needs to go increasing by `0.01`, i mean, 6.00*10^9, 6.01*10^9, 6.02*10^9, etc

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `Solve` and `Table` in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment to help you construct the code to find all of the solutions.

One should become one with one's function.  Using `Manipulate` is on of the best ways to do so.  Here are your two equations:

```
Manipulate[
 r = f a^0.5;
 Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, r]],
  Plot[-x/Tan[x], {x, -π, π}],
  Plot[-x/Tan[x], {x, π, 2 π}],
  Plot[-x/Tan[x], {x, -π, -2 π}],
  Plot[-x/Tan[x], {x, 2 π, 3 π}],
  Plot[-x/Tan[x], {x, -2 π, -3 π}],
  PlotRange -> 1.1 rmax {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Large, Bold] & ) /@ {"x", "y"}],
 {{f, fmin, Style["f", Large, Bold]}, fmin, fmax, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Initialization :> (a = 5.14 10^(-20);
   fmin = 6 10^9; fmax = 30 10^9;
   rmax = fmax a^0.5;)
 ]
```

[image: Plot of solutions]

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. How can I do to know the differents points where the circunference cuts the other function?

Comment: The interactive graphic shows that the number of intersection points increases with increasing radius.  You've also got a transcendental function and it is unlikely that there is a symbolic solution (or at least it's not obvious to me).  You can use `FindRoot` with a guess at each intersection point.